# SVG processing under Java on Android and desktop

Tags: java, android, svg

I am trying to write a Java application that will generate SVG image based on XML file. The application should also be able to show SVG file. My application should run on Android platform and desktop PCs. I read about Swing + Batik but afaik it will not work on Android. What is the best library to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidImageViewSVG.aspx) in Code Project deals with the subject. Two approaches are presented:

- android-libsvg library.
- Anti Grain Geometry engine.

Both solutions have dependencies on native code library, so you would need JNI.

There is also [svg4mobile](http://code.google.com/p/svg4mobile/) project, which only uses Java.

Answer (score 2):

per this thread: [libsvg ported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969037/svg-to-android-shape)

libsvg has been ported to android..see thread for details. You need a crystax form of NDK, ie exceptions enabled..build/install doc here at:[build-install-doc](https://answers.launchpad.net/libsvg-android/+question/127924)

Answer (score 2):

Also try this open-source library, Apache 2.0 license:

[SVG-Android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android)

Performance is good as the actual drawing is handled natively by an **android.graphics.Picture** object.

Comment: Can i create svg using this library in android ??

Comment: @RakeshGondaliya No, just load and render them.