# How to integrate Batik with Android to open & display SVG files?

Tags: android, svg, batik

I see on this post that Batik is the way to open SVG files with Android: [svg files rendering in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141544/svg-files-rendering-in-android)

But in the post is not explained how to integrate batik with android.

Someone know how to use Batik with Android to open and show SVG files?

thanks

Comment: Batik uses Java2d to render SVG. Android does not support Java2D, and has its own custom graphics API instead, so I would not expect Batik to work OOTB on Android. Getting Batik to work on Android would, in fact, involve a significant porting effort.